# performance testing C application Ubuntu

Tags: c, performance, ubuntu

We have an C application which is not written by me. We need to measure the performance in terms of CPU and memory usage. 
I have never done the performance test, therefore I am not aware of tools which can be used to get the CPU and memory consumption details.

I tried to search SO and google but I am not sure what to use and how to do.

It would be of great help to me if I can get some guidance here.

**EDIT:**
I am not looking for profilers which I understand tells about the performance of code blocks. I just want to monitor the resources consumed by the application. We are not going to improve the code. This is just for comparison with other products.
It's something what task manager shows in windows about each process. Just that I want.
I found few tools like nmon, munin, collectd, collectl but still confused how to use them. Trying to understand but any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The tool you need is a profiler this post has a lot of info:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794816/recommendations-for-c-profilers

Comment: Is the source code available?

Comment: Yes the source code is available.

Comment: @SamRedway I have used Valgrind to check memory leaks for few codes that I wrote but I am not sure how to use it for this. Basically, I run this as a service, like "service app start". Don't understand how to use it here.

Another point: I see profiler give information about the performance of different code blocks. What I need is overall resource usage when the application is servicing requests. Like for 1000 requests how much resources are used and likewise.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Yes the source code is available.

Comment: What's important to you? How long it takes for the application to execute? The average load of your CPU? The average utilization of your CPU? (They're slightly different.) Each is important for different types of applications - can you provide more information about the purpose of the application? (Though arguably, the only thing that ultimately matters is how long - in real life - a program takes to execute.  Everything else is dust in the wind/bits in the cloud.)

Comment: @tonysdg The thing important to us is the CPU and memory utilization.  We are not looking to improve the application, it is just to compare the performance with some other solutions. So, we just need the metrics about how much resource (CPU & RAM )it is consuming over a period of varying loads.